# Atuto increment column does not increses Id numer in mysql table

Tags: mysql

Why auto incremnt column does not increases id number in `Insert into from other mysql table` query ? Here is my query:

```
insert into tbl_1 (pk, col_a, col_b, col_c) 
select null,col_a, col_b, col_c from tbl_2
```

`pk` column in  `tbl_1` always returns same number i.e. '1', '1', '1'..... Can anyone tell me what is value I should select for auto increment column so that it will return '1', '2', '3',....and so on. I have large number of records in `tbl_2` and doesn't have `pk` column. It might be simple question but I am not able to solve it.

Comment: what is the ddl for your table, could you please show?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE  tbl_1 (
 `pk` BIGINT(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `col_a` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `col_b` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
 `col_c` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
 PRIMARY KEY (`pk`,`col_a`, `col_b`
);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **insert** query,

```
insert into tbl_1 (pk, col_a, col_b, col_c)
select null,col_a, col_b, col_c from tbl_2
```

to

```
insert into tbl_1 (col_a, col_b, col_c) 
select col_a, col_b, col_c from tbl_2
```

You don't need to specify the **auto increment** column while inserting.

For bulk insert **auto increment** will not work. You have to use diff method for that. For you try this query,

```
insert into tbl_1 (pk, col_a, col_b, col_c)
select @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank,col_a, col_b, col_c from tbl_2, (SELECT @curRank := 0) rn order by col_a
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: No, it doesn't work I tried before as well. It gives error like column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: dont use null  while inserting. You get that error because you are specifying extra value in values that is null,

Comment: If I do not use null in select statement, then it gives me '1', '1', '1', '1'..... in `pk` column as I explained in my question.

Comment: can you don one thing? just insert two record in the table tbl_1 i.e
insert into tbl_1 values('a','b','c');
insert into tbl_1 values('a','b','c');
and check your pk value.

Comment: Yes, it increments now. `insert into tbl_1  (pk, col_a, col_b, col_c) 
values ('a','b','c'),('a','b','c');` works fine. then where it goes worng when I select table instead values.

Comment: It works for individual values but I am not suppose to insert values. I need to insert values from `tbl_2`, unfortunately  which is not working properly.

Comment: could you please elaborate what exactly I need to do ? How can I use this sequence in my Insert into query ?

Comment: i have added a query, could you please try that? make sure your curRank value will be greater then your pk max value.

Comment: Perfectly works ! I just removed order by clause because it was disturbing order of my retrieval rows.  Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Have you any idea, if `tabl_2` is keep on updating every week and new rows are inserted automatically. So, I have new data to insert into `tabl_1` but without disturbing already existed data. So, my question is do not insert rows which already exist into `tabl_1` and insert new rows  from `tabl_2`. important thing is that, I do not have any special  `Id`  column in `tabl_2`. I tried by using left and right join but couldn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

No need to specify auto increment column in insert query.

`insert into tbl_1 (col_a, col_b, col_c) 
select col_a, col_b, col_c from tbl_2`